# Powershell script who scan directories name and remove them if the date contained in the name is older than 3 months

Tags: powershell, date, automation

**Hello,**

As i said before in the title, i would like to make a script who :

1. Only scan the directories
2. Scan the name of the directory ex.(ABC_20170504_12H03) and extract only the date (20170504).
3. Compare the date extracted before with the actual date minus 3 months.
4. Remove the directory if the date contained in the folder name is older than 3 months.

The problem is that i'm just starting to learn PowerShell, and this is my first task using this language. I'm a little bit lost and i would really appreciate some help.

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {
if((Get-Date).AddMonths(-3) -gt [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Name.Split("_")[1], "yyyyddMM", $null)) {
    Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf
  }         
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `$_.Name.split('_')[1]` in case of varying string length `ABC`.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try the script when i'll be home again.

Comment: Hello, first of all, thank you for the script, it's working perfectly after 2-3 corrections : `Get-ChildItem -Path "\path" | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer } | 
ForEach-Object {
  if((Get-Date).AddMonths(-3) -gt [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Name.Split("_")[1], "yyyyMMdd", $null)) 
  {
    Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force
  }         
}` I changed the "yyyyddMM" to "yyyyMMdd" and i added a -Recurse -Force to make sure everything is deleted.